# Python/Pandas/Matplotlib - Iterating/Looping Through Charts - Duplicate Charts Issue

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib

Trying to produce one chart for every 'query' with the 'keyword' on the x-axis and the 'trend' value on my y-axis.

This is my dataframe, called **'df'**.

```
                   query    keyword                     trend   sequence
1592    womens underwear    women's underwear on sale   1.40    1
1593    womens underwear    sale on womens underwear    1.40    2
1594    womens underwear    women's underwear for sale  1.40    3
1595    womens underwear    womens underwear sale       1.40    4
3687    womens underwear    womens underwear sale       1.40    5
3802    womens bra          lingerie sleepwear          124.00  1
1705    womens bra          women's n i t bracket       3.00    2
3852    womens bra          best bras for women         2.22    3
3826    womens bra          fantasy bra                 1.75    4
3851    womens bra          32 c bra                    1.71    5
```

What is happening is that I am producing 'n' charts in my for loop for each query. Many duplicates!

```
for i in df['query']:
   loopChart = df[df['query']==i]
   plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
   plt.bar(loopChart['keyword'], loopChart['trend'])
   plt.title(i)
   plt.xticks(rotation=90)
   plt.show()
```

I have tried a few things here with no luck:

1) Creating a sequence field (in my DF example) and using that to limit the output in my loopChart line

loopChart = df[df['query']==i & df['sequence']==1]

2) Using my sequence field as a nested while loop criteria

for i in df['query']:

while df['sequence'] <2:

Any insights on how else I might approach this challenge? Tried to think of ways to only go through and chart each 'query' once, but am stumped.

My end result should just be two bar charts, but right now it is 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disregard - I solved the issue with a small bit of code...added a .unique() to my for loop header and it all worked out.

```
for i in df['query'].unique():
   loopChart = df[df['query']==i]
   plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
   plt.bar(loopChart['keyword'], loopChart['trend'])
   plt.title(i)
   plt.xticks(rotation=90)
   plt.show()
```